# Question about a solution to a nonhomogeneous linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

(apologies for the format and somewhat vague title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution in words** Plug $\phi(t,\varepsilon)$ into your ODE. Differentiate both sides with respect to $\varepsilon$. Interchange derivatives in LHS. Use chain rule to calculate the derivative of the RHS (note that $\varepsilon$ appears in it twice). The zeroth order term will come from the middle argument of $v$; the inhomogeneity from the last argument.